# jQuery how to get the value of a query param from a clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a link like so:

```
<a href="/users/xxxx?width=640" class="dialogOnClick">Create Account</a>
```

I have

```
$('.dialogOnClick').live('click', function() {
    // How to get 640, given we look for the width param?
    console.log( $(this).?????)
});
```

When a user clicks on a link with the class dialogOnClick, I want to check if there is a width query param and if so, obtain the value. In the case above being 640. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element's `search` property will contain the query string.

Then you could either parse it into key & value pairs, or just use a regex for this simple example.

```
$('.dialogOnClick').live('click', function() {
    console.log( this.search.match(/width=(\d+)/)[1] );
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/s4syT/).

This will fail if there are no matches however. You may want to assign the return of `match()` to a variable and test if first to ensure it has required element.

Comment: +1, a more generic regular expression might be: `/width=([^&]*)/`.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks. You could also put `;` in that character class to fully support the spec :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.dialogOnClick').live('click', function() {

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var indexOfWidth = href.indexOf('width=');
    var value = href.substr(indexOfWidth).split("=")[1];

    console.log( value );
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/2nGRJ/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the trailing numeric value, then you can use:

```
this.href.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

However, if you specifically want the width value, you can use:

```
this.href.match(/width=\d+/)[0].match(/\d+$/)[0]
```

Or if you want a more robust method to get one parameter of many, then you need to parse the URL:

```
  function getParams(url) {
    var paramString = url.split('?')[1];
    var paramArray = [];
    var params = {};
    var p;

    if (paramString && paramString.length) {
      paramArray = paramString.split('&');

      for (var i=0, iLen=paramArray.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        p = paramArray[i].split('=');
        params[p[0]] = p[1];
      }
    }
    return params;
  }
```

and can do:

```
getParams(this.href)['width'];
```

POJS working example:

```
<a href="/users/xxxx?width=640" class="dialogOnClick"
  onclick="alert(this.href.match(/\d+$/)[0]);return false;">Create Account</a>

<a href="/users/xxxx?width=640" class="dialogOnClick"
  onclick="alert(getParams(this.href).width);return false;">Create Account 2</a>
```

Comment: Hey Rob, why the 2 step match for the number? What have I missed? Thanks.

Comment: @alex - nothing, I just didn't use grouping. :-) Of course when people ask questions like this, do they really want that specific value, or a more generic solution? I dunno, just filling in time...

Comment: Got it. +1 for in depth solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the contents of `href`:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

And a regular expression to parse that text to determine if there is a width parameter, and to extract the value:

```
var pattern = /width=([0-9]*)/g;
var match;    

while (match = pattern.exec(href))
{
    alert(match);
    // Do something with the match (["width=640", "640"]) here...
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/PYafe/).